# Playing a certain part of a large wav file

Tags: java, audio, wav, javasound

I want to play a certain parts of a wav file. Like playing the first ten seconds and then playing it from 50th-60th seconds and so on. I know how to play a entire wave file in Java using the start method of `SourceDataLine` class. Could anybody give me some pointers as to how I can seek a particular time position for audio and play it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Find the length of a frame, in bytes, from the `AudioFormat`
- Find the length in bytes of a second, by multiplying the frame size by the frame rate.
- `skip()` that amount of bytes.
- Play until the 2nd number of bytes calculated using the same formula.

Comment: That's exactly what I did after I got some idea from Marko's reply. Thanks for writing it down in steps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, nothing happens when you just call `start`. You are responsible for *pushing* the bytes of your choice into the line. So open a `RandomAccessFile`, seek to the appropriate offset, and execute a loop that transports the file data to the `SourceDataLine`.